# Pubsub Ack'd messages continuously re-deliver every 10s (Python beta client)

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

*Working with the beta Google Pub/Sub client (v0.28.3)*

Has anyone seen a scenario where the same message is constantly redelivered every 10s, even after acking it?

This goes beyond the at-least-once nature of Pub/Sub. It happens sporadically, but when it does occur we see the same message continuously for several hours.

I *suspect* it's because we process incoming messages in a background thread from the subscriber; but haven't yet been able to consistently reproduce it. Is that not kosher for some reason?

If a bug, happy to file it but operating on the assumption we're doing something wrong. Has anyone dealt with similar issues?

---

With debug logging we see something like:

```
D 13:51:46.000 Received response: received_messages { ... message_id: "155264162517414" ... }
D 13:51:46.000 New message received from Pub/Sub: %r
I 13:51:46.000 Processing Message: 155264162517414 
I 13:51:48.000 Acking Message: 155264162517414 
D 13:51:48.000 Sending request: ack_ids: "LDR..."
D 13:51:50.000 Snoozing lease management for 4.009431 seconds. 
D 13:51:50.000 Renewing lease for 0 ack IDs. 
D 13:51:50.000 The current p99 value is 10 seconds. 
...
D 13:51:59.000 Received response: received_messages { ... message_id: "155264162517414" ... }
D 13:51:59.000 New message received from Pub/Sub: %r
I 13:51:59.000 Processing Message: 155264162517414
```

---

Here's a toy version of code that shows how we are threading and this sometimes triggers the issue running locally:

```
import Queue
import logging
import threading
import random
import time
from google.cloud import pubsub


SUBSCRIPTION_PATH = ...


class Worker(threading.Thread):
    """Background thread to consume incoming messages."""
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = self.queue.get()
            self.process(message)
            print '<< Acking :', message.message_id
            message.ack()
            self.queue.task_done()

    def process(self, message):
        """Fake some work by sleeping for 0-15s. """
        s = random.randint(0, 15)
        print '>> Worker sleeping for ', s, message.message_id
        for i in range(s):
            time.sleep(1)
            print i


class Subscriber(threading.Thread):
    """Handles the subscription to pubsub."""
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='Subscriber')
        self.subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
        self.worker = Worker('FakeWorker')
        self.worker.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        self.worker.start()

        flow_control = pubsub.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
        policy = self.subscriber.subscribe(SUBSCRIPTION_PATH,
           flow_control=flow_control,
           callback=self._consume)
        print 'Sub started, thread', threading.current_thread()

    def _consume(self, message):
        self.worker.queue.put(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subscriber = Subscriber()
    subscriber.start()
    while 1:
        pass
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the at-least-once nature of Pub/Sub, acks in Pub/Sub are best effort. This means that there are two potential ways that an ack can "mess up".

1. The message can be successfully acked by Pub/Sub, and redelivered once (presumably due to a race condition).
2. The message can fail to be successfully acked.

In a world where the second situation obtains, the client library will not give you any kind of error (because the client library itself is not given one), and you will start seeing the message on a cadence (and this will be 10 seconds if your process times are short).

The solution to this is to simply ack the message again when you receive it. I *assume* (it is not clear from the toy code, so I am guessing) that you are simply ignoring repeat messages, but if you ack the repeat, you should stop getting it.

If you *are* re-acking the message, then please [open an issue](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-python/issues) against the client library.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Luke. I believe we've been acking these repeated messages. Unf, the implication of the best effort ack redelivery is that we have to keep a cluster-wide cache of processed messages which isn't exactly ideal. For now we switched over to Google's prod HTTP-based library; and filed a support ticket.